# What is this language or DB?

Tags: database

A friend ask to migrate his application database to a new SQL Server.

The thing is the application is very old (1999) and no manual or anything.

My guess is something like FoxPro or DBase.

**Any idea how I can open those files?**

The SCT files have some FORM description and are text files.(BTW: app is in spanish.)
Then are some OCT files binary files.
And then is the Database BDSIAM.txt in a folder with several files maybe those are tables like

```
AR_BA150.DAT
AR_BA150.IDX
```

[image]

SAME FILE more lines

```
tables
ar_basico         
end tables

variables
muni = vartable.mun char
fechadia = vartable.fecha date
default today
a = ar_basico.bas_tipo 
f2 = ar_basico.bas_iden 
f3 = ar_basico.bas_nomb 
f4 = ar_basico.bas_dire 
lines      1
f5 = ar_basico.bas_feci 
f6 = ar_basico.bas_telf 
end variables
menu menu6 "SELECCIONE"
option "Incluir"
add

option "Consultar"
query

option "Imprime"
output
option "Salir"
exit program
end menu
```

Comment: I found this from Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/KB/130686 Is it possible these are old foxpro files?

Comment: You are right the SCT files are foxpro, but still cant find anything for the OCT. Or how the tables are save as DAT/IDX

Comment: What does the oct file look like?

Comment: Looks like querys. Have some order by, But is binary file. Some lot of weirds characters.

Comment: My guess is some sort of memo filed looking at the rest of the file extension patterns. Is there any code that tries to specifically open an oct file?

Comment: This thing is huge, have 1152 files, still looking. DB folder have 200 elements

Comment: I see an octree format after searching but that's about it. http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/fileextensionsfull.asp, http://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/oct

Comment: .DAT and .IDX might indicate old BTrieve databases. They used DBISAM format, although I'm not familiar enough to remember if they used .OCT extensions. (I did a BTrieve related project back in the mid to late 1990s for a client; it was rather nasty.)

Answer (score 0):

That is very close to Informix SQL, and the Perform screen language.  The only part that isn't an exact match is `define` on line 2 and `form` on line 3.  Is there an `attributes` section after the lines shown?  And perhaps a `tables` section?

The `.dat` and `.idx` files are also Informix C-ISAM, but the suffixes are fairly obvious and other systems probably also use them.

I wonder if this might even be the pre-SQL version, Informix 3.30 or thereabouts (last released, 1986).

---

With the extra information, I can see that this is not Informix, though the concepts and much of the notation are very similar indeed.

Comment: There is a variables section and table section. I include the rest of the file. What about the .oct files? i also found some .lnk files windows think are direct access.